# Query Amazon Redshift without using jdbc driver

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to do SQL query on redshift database without using JDBC. (I don't want to connect to JDBC to execute a SQL command in the redshift as shown in this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-in-code.html).

I'm connecting AmazonRedshift using redshift client builder

```
AmazonRedshift client = AmazonRedshiftClientBuilder.standard()
        .withCredentials(awsCredentials).build();
```

Now I want to execute a SQL query using this client. I googled and found this example (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/managing-events-java.html) where they are using DescribeEventsRequest to get the events but I'm not sure whether this is the same API I should use to run SQL commands

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The AWS SDK (`AmazonRedshift` client), can only be used to manage the Redshift cluster (create, delete, manage events, etc.) It cannot be used to execute queries.

To execute queries, you must use JDBC.